# Azure appinsight Trace and exception message length exceeds the limit

Tags: azure, appinsights

I try to log exceptions to azure appinsights. The exception message length exceeds the limit of Trace and exception message length. Is there a way to work around this limit? Thanks

Comment: No you can't https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/20208607-application-insights-increase-length-of-message-p